# C# Adding column values and outputting to label

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get a few labels to output the sum of columns loaded into the datagridview.

This is what I've put together and when debugging it, it does proper math for the first rule but then jumps the rest of the code and never reads the output code and continues to load the form.

Not sure if it matters but not all values in each column are numerical values (a `DateTime` and `string` are in a couple others), I'm positive the row[] numbers are correct for the data I need.

```
LoadData();

// ISSUE STARTS HERE
int PartsTotal = 0;
int SuppliesTotal = 0;
int ReplacementTotal = 0;
int RecycleTotal = 0;
int ReturnTotal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i) 
{
    PartsTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    
    SuppliesTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    
    ReplacementTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    
    RecycleTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    
    ReturnTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
}

lblPartsTotal.Text = PartsTotal.ToString("c");
lblPartsTotal.Visible = true;

lblPartsTotal.Text = PartsTotal.ToString("c");
lblPartsTotal.Visible = true;

lblReplacementTotal.Text = ReplacementTotal.ToString("c");
lblReplacementTotal.Visible = true;
lblRecycleTotal.Text = RecycleTotal.ToString("c");
lblRecycleTotal.Visible = true;

lblReturnsTotal.Text = ReturnTotal.ToString("c");
lblReturnsTotal.Visible = true;
```

Comment: may be the `Convert.ToInt32()`  throwing some FormatException, Try `int32.TryParse`

Comment: I would set a break and make sure that you have rows enough.